# WPF Usercontrol caller didnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have the mainwindow. I call the Usercontrols in the mainwindow. I call Usercontrol1 in the mainwindow.loaded section. I would like to bring Usercontrol2 instead of Usercontrol1 by clicking on a button inside Usercontrol1.

My usercontrol caller class:

```
 public class uc_call
{
    public static void uc_add(Grid grd, UserControl uc)
    {
        if (grd.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            grd.Children.Clear();
            grd.Children.Add(uc);
        }
        else
        {
            grd.Children.Add(uc);
        }
    }
}
```

My Mainwindow_Loaded(It works):

```
uc_call.uc_add(Content, new UserControl1());
```

Button Click function in UserControl1:

```
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        uc_call.uc_add(mw.Content, new Usercontrol2());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create a new MainWindow. Instead, use the existing one:

```
var topLevelPanel = Application.Current.MainWindow.Content as Panel;

if (topLevelPanel != null)
{
    topLevelPanel.Children.Clear();
    topLevelPanel.Children.Add(new Usercontrol2());
}
```

Note that is doesn't hurt to call `Children.Clear()` even when the collection is empty.

---

In case you've added another `Content` property that holds the Grid where you want to replace the child elements:

```
var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
var grid = mainWindow.Content;
grid.Children.Clear();
grid.Children.Add(new Usercontrol2());
```

or with your static method:

```
var mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
uc_call.uc_add(mw.Content, new Usercontrol2());
```

Comment: I want the usercontrols to change on a grid inside Mainwindow. When I do what you say, all the objects inside mainwindow are lost. How can I make mainwindow's objects stay?

Comment: my desing and usercontrol1: https://ibb.co/fkOcVG  -- I want usercontrol2 to replace usercontrol1 but when click button: https://ibb.co/npb9cw

Comment: `topLevelPanel` here is your top level Grid, that you've assigned to the MainWindow's Content (i.e. `mw.Content`) property. Or have you added another `Content` field or property?